# Posts/comments don't onebox in chat

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, meta

[Some more remnants](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198/community-building-missing-from-network-profile) of the chaos [Moderators SE → Community Building SE rename](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193/changing-the-name-of-moderators-se-the-saga-continues) are still coming up, mainly for Meta CB. For example, there is an [issue loading meta posts on the mobile app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244616/android-stackexchange-app-doesnt-let-me-open-questions-in-my-feed-that-link-to-a).

Something that we noticed in chat is meta comments don't onebox: [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19348601#19348601), [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19343634#19343634), and [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19343649#19343649). It's only Meta CB comments that don't one box; [comments from the main site still onebox](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19348638#19348638). Why is this happening?

**Edit:** apparently ***no [posts](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19348754#19348754) are [oneboxing](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19348767#19348767).*** Odd.

---

Other (seemingly) related issues:

- [Meta posts don't load from mobile apps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244616/186281)
- [Meta post oneboxes look different and are missing elements](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/224/78)
- [Community Building doesn't exist in Data Explorer](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/225/78)

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19348938#19348938 this oneboxes...

Answer (score 6):

This will be fixed as of build 2782 (it affects Computer Graphics Meta too).